# The object from my Node module does not have the behavior I expect - Node.js

Tags: node.js, module, export

I am a newbie with Node and I am trying to learn how to make my modules work. Here is my express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var client = require('./config/postgres.js');

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM users');
  query.on('row', function(row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  query.on('end', function(result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

And here is my module that I am trying to `require`

```
var pg = require('pg').native;
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/isx';
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
module.exports.client = client;
```

but in my main app, my client `has no method 'query'`.  If I just inline the code that is in the `module` and I am `require`ing in, then everything works fine.  What is the difference between the 2 ways to access the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var client = require('./config/postgres.js');
```

...sets client equal to the `export` object in your import. Since the export object has a single `client` property with the `query` function,

```
client.client.query()
```

is what you're looking for.

If you want to export just the client, use;

```
module.exports = client;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are exporting this:

```
{
    "client": [Function]
 }
```

Just access the key that stores the function when you `require` the module or export only the function and nothing more:

```
module.exports = client;
```